# TS Printer Redirection Issue

Tags: windows-xp, troubleshooting, printing, terminal-services

I am stumped by a printer redirection problem we are having on various PCs throughout our network.  We use RDP (Server 2008r2) to have users log into our farm and access our ERP.  Since we have multiple locations, each store has printers installed locally, and they are simply shared among each other.

The problem is this, though:  Some PCs (Windows XP SP3) will NOT redirect particular printers.  For example, I have one computer that prints locally (this is a shared printer attached to another computer), and it's port is set to use USB (not DOT4).  I've updated the Remote Desktop Client to 7.0, and I've even applied the fix that Microsoft suggests [http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;302361] by adding a DWORD value in the registry to allow all printers to be redirected, but still no dice.

There doesn't appear to be anything in particular that is causing this issue - it can happen to various models of printers or PCs.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I guess you are using Server 2008 Easy Print ?

Comment: After working with this issue for a while I've come to the conclusion that our MSP hasn't installed all of the correct drivers on our terminal servers.  It seems that if we use different drivers which may/may not cause printing issues (one printer doesn't like PLC5 drivers), the printers magically appear.  So, it's been passed off to our MSP.

Comment: And to directly answer your question, yes, Easy Print is enabled.

Comment: Do you have the printer drivers equivalence ? I mean if workstations have PCL drivers then on server should be PCL. Same for PS or others.